# Map Algebra with Zero-inflated regression weights

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, regression

I have a non-normal count variable y and 6 rasters x1 to x6, each mapped onto a (n x n) grid. I have applied a zero-inflated negative binomial regression using the pscl package of R. I now need to generate a risk map using a raster calculator. In [this](https://www.questia.com/library/journal/1P3-3687979891/risk-terrain-modeling-for-spatial-risk-assessment) paper, the authors weight their maps after a Poisson regression using the expression

`Exp(\beta_0+\sum(\beta_i * x_i))/Exp(\beta_0)`

In the current case I have two additional parameters: the log of theta, and the intercept of the zero-inflation model. How can I modify the expression to incorporate my weights? I cannot upload the data as they are large. Any solution using QGIS, the raster package of R, or ArcGIS will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Here you are effectively asking three questions i.e. how to do this using QGIS, how to do this using R and how to do this using ArcGIS Desktop.  To fit our focussed Q&A format can you please [edit] your question to limit it to whichever of those products you are trying to do this in first, please?